# Difference between string& and string in c++

Tags: c++, string

Basically the title. I saw a c++ program use string& somewhere, but don't know why it uses that instead of string. I tried to Google it but google ignores the & sign. What is the difference between string and string&?

Comment: Just FYI, this search engine lets you search symbols: http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: For more detail you probably have to show a minimal example of code you are talking about. With that said this will likely be a duplicate but duplicates are not always easy to find.

Comment: When passing a string to a function, std::string& is more like std::string* in the sense that the string won't be copied. But unlike a pointer (*) it is never allowed to be a nullptr. It MUST point to (refer to) an instance. Thus it is called a reference. If you pass a std::string to a function it will be copied so that changing it won't have side effects.
If you want to avoid copying AND avoid changes you use a const reference and pass the string like (const std::string& st)

Comment: This happens a lot with C and C++ and is one of the reasons I recommend learning the fundamentals of a programming language from books. The Internet is helpful later after you know the terminology and how to tell the ravings of a madman from a good quality program.

Answer (score 3):

The data type **string&** literally means “a reference to a string object.”

There are 3 things how can the **&** be meaned:

1. Reference declaration/parameter.
2. Address-of operator.
3. Bitwise And operator.

Check a question [ampersand (&) at the end of variable etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864574/ampersand-at-the-end-of-variable-etc/20864587)

Comment: What do you mean "whose contents will not be changed"? I don't see a `const` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, post edited.

Comment: You should also mention what happens when `std::string&` versus `std::string` in function parameters.  Most of the time I see `std::string7` its with function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

&string is a reference to the string object whereas the string is the object.

Comment: I thought `std::string&` is a reference to a string and `std::string * p = &string_variable;` is the address of the string.